# Use Jquery to resize div width when wrapping

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to change the width of a div  (I'm using it as an inline block) to become exactly the necessary width needed whenever some of its contents wrap?

I'm not too experienced in Jquery..

Also, I'm using the version 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

```
width:auto
```

or

```
$("#yourid").css("width", "auto");
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/YsjsS/3/)

Comment: if i have images wrapping, there is a large space on the right hand side that i would like to get rid of.. the space where it's not big enough to fit the image..

Comment: Here is a more concise question I have posted with full details and sample code: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657349/android-2-3-stock-browser-inline-block-not-expanding-on-orientationchange-eve)