# Android 2.3 Stock Browser: Inline-block not expanding on "orientationchange" event

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I currently have an interesting problem going on with my website when it comes to orientation changes on android 2.3. It's strictly for mobile, with necessary support for Android 2.3+ stock browser. See below..

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
    {
    text-align: center;
    }
#parent
    {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align; left;
    }

.dummy
    {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);

        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#parent > .dummy").remove();

            var currentOffset = $("#parent > #child:first-child").offset().top;

            $("#parent > #child").each(function() {
                if (currentOffset != $(this).offset().top)
                    {
                    $("<div class=\"dummy\"></div>").insertBefore(this);
                    currentOffset = $(this).prev().offset().top; 
                    }
            });

        }, 500);
});

$(window).bind("orientationchange", function() {
        $(window).resize();
});
```

Basically, the above code parent holds a bunch of `inline-block` divs. the wrapper centers the parent, and any child div that wraps to the next line ion the parent is left aligned. This works as expected.

The problem I face with this setup is that when a child wraps to the next line, there's a good amount of white space on the right hand side in the parent.

I wrote that jquery function which first looks at each child div. When it detects that a child has wrapped, it adds a `<div class="dummy"></div>` element right before itself, which basically creates a "line break." This removes the white space on the right hand side in the parent, thus re-positioning the parent to the very center of the view. This function is called on the "`orientationchange`" event, removing any dummy divs found prior.

Now my problem - On Android 2.3 browser, switching from portrait mode to landscape mode doesn't expand the parent's width beyond the width of what it is in portrait mode. Obviously, if I load the page for the first time in landscape mode, it renders correctly, but the second I switch to portrait, then back to landscape, the issue returns.

Sorry this is lengthy but I really want to find a solution to this, and have tried many things, even setting the parent's max-width to some hard-coded large value, but no dice.

Thanks for everyone's help in advance!